# How can I standardize inconsistent vertical alignment of text across browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

The text below appears vertically centered within the container.

[image: example of correct behavior]

The problem is that vertical alignment of the text is not consistent across platforms/browsers. On Firefox on macOS, Chrome on Android, and Chrome on Windows, the text looks like this:

[image: example of incorrect behavior]

Notice how the text is slightly closer to the top edge of the blue container.

I've tried various fixes using `vertical-align: middle` or different combinations of `height`/`line-height` to no avail.

Here's the code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhyw39qj/)):

html:

```
<h1 class="title">
  This is a title
</h1>
```

css:

```
.title {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it will fix exactly your problem but I normally use https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to fix this type of inconsistencies.

Comment: @DanielDoblado Thanks for the idea but I just read through the source and it does not address this as far as I can tell. (https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css)